# Print from HTML to dot-matrix-printer

Tags: html, css, printing

I have an HTML that I want to print to a dot-matrix-printer, the printer I'm using is EPSON LX-310, I want to print into A5 landscape, the output did not go as I expected to be. 2 methods i tried but the result all not good.

**1st method**

The code

[image: The code]

The printer setup

[image: The printer setup]

The result on A4 paper

[image]

**2nd method**

I have added CSS to set the page size and rotation

The code

[image: The code]

The printer setup

[image: The printer setup]

The result on A4 paper

[image: The result]

Do you guys have any advice on how to resolve this issue? Thanks before.

Comment: Use a larger `font-size`. Printing from a browser is largely about converting the page into an image and then printing that image. Your results are typical of trying to scale an image to a lower resolution.